# Flushing output before rendering completed in Symfony/Twig

Tags: php, performance, symfony, twig

Is it possible to flush output buffer before rendering completed? My point is to improve perceived performance of the website.

E.g. there is a big table (like 5 000 rows) in admin interface to be rendered. I'd like to tell Twig/Symfony to flush output right after `</head>` has been rendered, so the browser can start downloading styles/javascript, and then flush output after every 500 rows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want to use is the Twig `{% flush %}` command which is the equivalent of the PHP function `flush()`. Place it right after the `</head>` tag in your template for it to send the current buffer to the browser. Each time you call it it will output any output buffered so putting it in a loop will work fine.

For more info see the [docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/flush.html).