# Flushing sequentially HTML table rows with Symfony/Twig

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I am adapting a standard HTML/PHP code to Symfony 4.4/Twig.
The adapted code runs fine except a part where a HTML table that is sequentially updated by flushing the output buffer (every 1-2 sec, as soon as new row data is available):

```
echo “<tr> <td>Element1</td> … <td> ElementN</td> </tr>”;
ob_flush(); flush();
```

I can render the complete table (when all rows are available) through a Twig template in a controller with `return $this->render('template.html.twig');`, BUT I am unable to update the HTML page for displaying the table row by row as in the original code. This is blocking as I need to get results on the fly, not waiting for hours to see the first rows.

I unsuccessfully tried the Twig `{% flush %}` command place right after the  tag in the template as suggested here: [Flushing output before rendering completed in Symfony/Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944977/flushing-output-before-rendering-completed-in-symfony-twig)

Could you please provide me suggestions to progress?
Thanks by advance.

Comment: `as soon as new row data is available` - What you mean with this? You build the whole dataset *before*  rendering the output?

Comment: I build one table row and I want to render its output (not waiting for the rest of the table data), and then same for all next rows until the end of the table. ob_flush(); flush(); worked well, but no longer since I use Symfony/Twig and I am unable yet to use correctly {% flush %}. Thank you

Comment: Where do you build this row, inside your controller right?

Comment: Exactly.
And I tried inserting the {% flush %} at different locations in the template, but I don't really see how to trigger it, should I call render() after every row building? I also tried but nothing worked. Thanks

Comment: Well `flush` wont work as you are processing everything before sending output to the browser

Comment: I am fully ok to send a partial output to the browser after I built a row, and then complete this output sequentially with next rows, but I don't know how to do these "sequential renderings" with Symphony/Twig. Thanks

Comment: Guess u'll need to use a `StreamedResponse`. First render the header, then process the rows and then render the footer - [reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#streaming-a-response)

Comment: Thanks a lot DarkBee for your analysis and suggestion.
Here is the result of my 2 new investigations:
1. Inside Symfony/Twig, just with the pointed code:
$response = new StreamedResponse();
$response->setCallback(function () {
    var_dump('Text1');
    flush();
    sleep(2);
    var_dump('Text2');
});
$response->send();
It displays the 2 texts BUT both only after the sleep(), so NOT streamed as needed.
I tried multiple header settings, with ob_flush+flush, just flush, ... Nothing works yet. :-(

Comment: 2. Outside Symfony/Twig. This simple code works still perfectly with the same env:
echo('Text1'); 
ob_flush(); flush();
sleep(2);
echo ('Text2');

Comment: In the chain of output buffers (from PHP to the web server), I am now suspecting that there is one needing a large buffer size before finally rendering.

Answer (score 1):

After few new investigations, I understand much better the issue, and I found an acceptable workaround.

The behavior difference comes from the output data buffering of the tool chain: PHP, server API (gateway between PHP and web server), web server.

1. The PHP buffer has 4KB by default (defined by the output_buffering param in php.ini)
2. The server API buffer has usually 0KB for Apache Handler, 4KB for CGI/FastCGI
3. The web server buffer for Apache or Symfony local web is likely 8KB

My orignal XAMPP config uses Apache Handler + Apache and reacts well to flush commands.
My new Symfony config uses CGI/FastCGI + its local web and does NOT react to them.
Both uses the same PHP 7.4 install.
I used various codes which confirm the size of the Symfony chain buffer at 8KB: as soon as reached the data output is displayed in the browser.
I did not find yet a way to reduce the Symfony chain buffer, so the workaround is to artificially fill my rows with an invisible HTML comment to the 8KB threshold. It is not so elegant, but there is no perf impact in my application.
I successfully tried different Twig objects/functions: simple Response/setContent, StreamedResponse/setCallback and Response/render. The cleanest seems to be the following:

```
`$response = new Response();
$HTML = "Text1";
$response = $this->render('Sandbox/row.html.twig', ['String' => $HTML]);
$response->send();
sleep(2);           // Just to simulate the processing time between 2 rows
$HTML = "Text2";
$response = $this->render('Sandbox/row.html.twig', ['String' => $HTML]);
return($response);`
```